# "Template" posts

Tags: nodes

I have a site that often needs nearly identical content posted with slight variations. For example, "Business is closed today due to severe weather," as the content and "Closed 1/26/14" as the title.  Obviously the title should vary from one posting to the next, but the body of the message doesn't need to change.  (This is an overly simple example, just so the post can be easy to read.)

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I would look into the https://drupal.org/project/token module and if you have any further questions, add some more detail to help fine tune an eventual answer.

Comment: Jimajamma: Thanks for the reply. I'm not asking about the "token-ness" of the task. I'm asking if there is a way to make a "copy-paste" or "boilerplate" style of posting. My users need to post "we're closed today due to snow" type messages about 5 - 10 times per year and all the posts have to have the same content body. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, you could create a content type without a body field and instead just one text field.  The text field could be populated with via a select or bunch of radio buttons that had the array of acceptable answers, eg, "We are closed today", "We are open today", "We have a sale on shoes today," etc.  And then using the token module and either the auto title module or your own programming, it could be used to set the title as "Closed [today]" or "Sale [today]" or even "[short-reason] [today]" etc so your users didn't need to worry about creating a standard title as well.